# Não deveria ter a lista de privilégios aqui?

Tags: bug, status-intencional, internacionalização

Em outros sites da rede há uma lista com os privilégios do meta. Aqui há a [página](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) mas não a lista.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Privilege list is only available on "main" sites, not on meta sites: see https://meta.superuser.com/help/privileges as another example.

Comment: I know but I saw this page in other sites. Anyway, I agree.

Comment: Are the actual privileges on meta based on the main site rep, or on meta's hidden rep?

Comment: They are the same, since rep is the same :-) There's no meta "hidden" rep...